# Should adverb come after where clause or before if it is the end of the sentence

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatically & meaninfully correct sentence to use in the following case:

> ... we deal with the special cases where [description of what we mean
>   by "special case"] seperately.

or

> ... we deal with the special cases separately where [description of
>   what we mean by "special case"]

Comment: *This is a special case **where the comment contains an example of the construction being queried**.* Alternatively: *This comment is a special case **containing** an example of the construction being queried* (which doesn't contain a "relative pronoun" such as ***where, which, that,*** etc.). But if your *[description of what "special case" means]* is relatively lengthy, it would be clumsy to include a lot of distracting text before ***separately***, since by the time he reaches it, the reader may have forgotten what it refers back to (how we will deal with these special cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one sounds much better but both are acceptable.

Another way to say it that sounds fluent is:

... we deal separately with the special cases separately where [description of what we mean by "special case"]

Comment: The "another way" you suggested is an acceptable alternative to the first sentence, but I would contend that the second sentence is not acceptable, since the "where" clause isn't connected to the "special cases" anymore.